# Is there a way to load user library's from specific location ONLY on running the binary

Tags: c, unix, gcc

I have a shared library's libmyworld.so in /opt/my_prog/lib and also in /home/user1/lib
Irrespective of the order I specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user1/lib;/opt/myprog/lib); my binary SHOULD always look for libmyworld.so FIRST in /opt/my_prog/lib;

Can this be done using GCC during compilation time? without modifying my_prog binary. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The search order for dynamic libraries in Linux (from ld.so man page) is the following

> - Using the DT_RPATH dynamic section attribute of the binary
>     if present and DT_RUNPATH attribute does not exist.  Use of
>         DT_RPATH is deprecated.
> - Using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Except if
>         the executable is a setuid/setgid binary, in which case it
>         is ignored.
> - Using the DT_RUNPATH dynamic section attribute of the binary
>         if present.
> - From the cache file /etc/ld.so.cache which contains a
>         compiled list of candidate libraries previously found in the
>         augmented library path. If, however, the binary was linked
>         with -z nodeflib linker option, libraries in the default
>         library paths are skipped.
>
>   - In the default path /lib, and then /usr/lib.  If the binary
>       was linked with -z nodeflib linker option, this step is
>       skipped.

When linking, to set

- DT_RUNPATH: use -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-R$(RUNPATH)
- DT_RPATH:   use -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,-R$(RPATH)

In theory, it is better to use DT_RUNPATH as the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, on which the user has a control, has precedence.  But here you want to avoid the user control, so use the DT_RPATH. In you link line:

```
-Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,-R/opt/my_prog/lib
```

Comment: Thanks AProgrammer :) and I also find any interesting link which talks more on this http://blog.lxgcc.net/?tag=dt_rpath

Answer (score 0):

You can always launch your binary (here called *foo*) with

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/my_prog/lib foo
```

or make a shell script with the line above.

Comment: @datenwolf: An answer which solves a problem does not deserve a negative vote just because another answer is preferred.

Comment: Your suggested method is not very robust and can break under various circumstances, for example if a plugin .so is loaded with a custom version of a common library set with -Wl,--rpath; setting this variable on that library would break that plugin. I'Ve come across a lot of wrapper scripts, that use LD_LIBRARY_PATH in that manner which eventually broke some part of the program executed through it.

Answer (score 0):

While compiling your source code use the below command
gcc -o [desired_executable_file_name] -L [Your shared library path] -l [your shared library name] -I [Header file path]

for example in your case
gcc -o my_word_exe -L /opt/my_prog/lib -lmyworld -I [header path if their]

Then it"ll take libmyworld.so in /opt/my_prog/lib this path

Comment: This will not adjust the order in which the system linker is looking for library. One must add another static search path to the ELF. See AProgrammer's answer for how to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Use LD_PRELOAD.

`LD_PRELOAD=/home/lib/libmyworld.so mybinary`

The advantage is that you don't fiddle with LD_LIBRARY_PATH - your binary may depend on other shared libraries and it may need proper `LD_LIBRARY_PATH/ld.so.conf/whatever`.

PS. This is the least invasive and flexible solution, because does not affect loading of other libraries and does not hardcode paths in the user executable.

Comment: I hope you feel better and relaxed now.